# Kotlintest interceptor and lateinit vars

Tags: testing, kotlin

I have some testcases that share a common setup. They all need two fields which can be initialized in the same way. So I thought I can extract them into `lateinit var` fields and create them in an test-case-interceptor. 
But when I try to access them in my testcases they always throw an exception because they are not initialized. 
Is there a way to create the fields before every testcase?

Here is my code so far:

```
class ElasticsearchFieldImplTest : WordSpec() {

    // These 2 are needed for every test
    lateinit var mockDocument: ElasticsearchDocument
    lateinit var mockProperty: KProperty<*>

    override fun interceptTestCase(context: TestCaseContext, test: () -> Unit) {
        // Before Each
        mockDocument = mock()
        mockProperty = mock {
            on {name} doReturn Gen.string().generate()
        }

        // Execute Test
        test()

        // After Each
    }

    init {
        "ElasticsearchFields" should {
            "behave like normal var properties" {
                val target = ElasticsearchFieldImpl<Any>()
                // Here the exception is thrown
                target.getValue(mockDocument, mockProperty) shouldBe null

                val testValue = Gen.string().generate()
                target.setValue(mockDocument, mockProperty, testValue)
                target.getValue(mockDocument, mockProperty) shouldBe testValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I step through it with a debugger and set a breakpoint in the `interceptTestCase` methods I see that it is executed before the test and that the properties are initialized. Then I step forward to the test and in it the properties are not initialized anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клаус Шварц's answer is incorrect. This is not how kotlintest works - **in `init` lambdas are only created, not run.** So you are not accessing your `lateinit var`s in `init` block. They just never have any value assigned.

This doesn't work because of bug in kotlintest, described (and actually almost resolved) here: https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/issues/174

In short - `interceptTestCase` is called on different instance of class than real tests. So it has no influence on your tests at all.

Workaround is to override property:
`override val oneInstancePerTest = false`

Then there is only one instance and `interceptTestCase` works correctly, but you have to remember - **there is only one instance for all tests**.

Kotlintest 3.0 will be free of this bug. (But possibly might have one instance for all tests by default.)

Answer (score 0):

You should not access `lateinit vars` before they were initialized.

The problem is that you are accessing your `lateinit var`s inside `init {}` block, which is default constructor and it is called before `interceptTestCase()`.

The easiest way here is just to make `mockDocument` and `mockProperty` nullable.

```
var mockDocument: ElasticsearchDocument? = null
var mockProperty: KProperty<*>? = null
```

and if you want you test to crash if these fields were not initialized add `!!` modifier:

```
init {
    "ElasticsearchFields" should {
        "behave like normal var properties" {
            val target = ElasticsearchFieldImpl<Any>()
            // Here the exception is thrown
            target.getValue(mockDocument!!, mockProperty!!) shouldBe null

            val testValue = Gen.string().generate()
            target.setValue(mockDocument!!, mockProperty!!, testValue)
            target.getValue(mockDocument!!, mockProperty!!) shouldBe testValue
        }
    }
}
```